# Reuse subquery without using temp table or WITH clause in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle 11g, I have a table, named `ITEM`, in which each record was categorize into `maingroup` and `subgroup` as follows:

```
+-------+---------+----------+
 item_id maingroup subgroup
+-------+---------+---------+
       1 group1    subgroup1
       2 group1    subgroup2
       3 group2    subgroup1
       4 group2    subgroup2
 ...
```

I have to write a program to report number of items in table `ITEM`. The report output will be similar to this:

```
                 subgroup1   subgroup2   group_total
group1                  10           5            15
group2                   0           1             1
subgroup_total          10           6            16
```

To do that, I will write an SQL to query the data and then reformat the output using Java. The SQL should make the complete report itself, i.e. I will use Java only to reformat the output and not to do any calculation. So, I decided that the output of the SQL should be like this:

```
+--------------+-----------+-----+
 maingroup      subgroup    cnt
+--------------+-----------+-----+ 
 group1         subgroup1      10
 group1         subgroup2       5
 group1         group_total    15
 group2         subgroup1       0
 group2         subgroup2       1
 group2         group_total     1
 subgroup_total subgroup1      10
 subgroup_total subgroup2       6
 subgroup_total group_total    16
```

Ideally, the SQL would be as simple as

```
select maingroup, subgroup, count(*) cnt from ITEM 
group by maingroup, subgroup union all
select maingroup, 'group_total' as subgroup, count(*) cnt from ITEM
group by maingroup union all
select 'subgroup_total' as maingroup, subgroup, count(*) cnt from ITEM
group by subgroup;
```

But no, I simplified the table `ITEM` the make the question easy to understand, actually, to make up this `ITEM`, I have to use a big subquery, so it's actually looks like

```
select maingroup, subgroup, count(*) cnt from 
       (select maingroup, subgroup from ...) ITEM 
group by maingroup, subgroup union all
select maingroup, 'group_total' as subgroup, count(*) cnt from 
       (select maingroup, subgroup from ...) ITEM 
group by maingroup union all
select 'subgroup_total' as maingroup, subgroup, count(*) cnt from
       (select maingroup, subgroup from ...) ITEM 
group by subgroup;
```

which use the same big subquery 3 times. I wish I can reuse this subquery but I don't have permission to create tables or to use the WITH clause. **Is it possible to rearrange the above SQL such that the subquery `ITEM` is process only once without creating temporary table or using the WITH clause?**

Comment: What about creating a `(materialized) view` ? Do you have permissions to create a `view` ?

Comment: @avk unfortunately, I don't have that permission also.

Comment: Why don't you have *permission* to use the WITH clause; that isn't a privilege (like creating a table or MV), so is that a restriction being imposed on you for some reason?

Comment: @AlexPoole Actually, when I use the WITH clause, it return no data and as this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506499/oracle-with-clause-returns-no-data) suggest, I assume it is due to permission issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a query with `grouping sets` clause:

```
SELECT coalesce( maingroup, 'subgroup_total' ) As maingroup,
       coalesce( subgroup, 'group_total' ) As subgroup,
       count(*) cnt 
FROM very_complex_subquery
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((maingroup, subgroup), (maingroup), (subgroup))
order by 1,2
;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ed9b/4